# GitLab-CI: run job only when all conditions are met

Tags: gitlab-ci

In [GitLab-CI document](https://docs.gitlab.com/ce/ci/yaml/README.html#only-and-except-simplified), I read the following contents:

> In this example, job will run only for refs that are tagged, **or** if a build is explicitly requested via an API trigger **or** a Pipeline Schedule:
>
> ```
> job:
>   # use special keywords
>   only:
>     - tags
>     - triggers
>     - schedules
> ```

I noticed the document uses **or** instead of **and**, which means the job is run when either one condition is met. But what if I want to configure a job to only run when all conditions are met, for instance, in a Pipeline Schedule **and** on master branch?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your specific question is how do I only run a pipeline on **`master` when it was scheduled** this should work:

```
job:
  only:
    - master
  except:
    - triggers
    - pushes
    - external
    - api
    - web
```

In this example you exclude all except for the `schedules` 'trigger' and only run for the `master` branch.

Comment: But if GitLab adds a new type of 'trigger' in the future, the `except` clause will require update.

Comment: That is true, although you only need to add except clauses that you actualy use. For example the projects I use only get triggerd by pushes or schedules. So adding the web clause is nice but never used

Comment: Okay you do have a point there. I guess this solution, though technically is like a workaround, is good enough.

Comment: I have a merge request from `myOwnRepo/develop` to `mainRepo/develop` and I want the `deploy` job runs ONLY when my merge request IS MERGED. How does the config look like?

Comment: in GItlab >= 12.3 its possible without that workaround: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/yaml/#rules

Comment: It's unclear though from the documentation about how the "only"/"except" special keywords should be used with "rules".

Answer (score 0):

Updated - 2023

> But what if I want to configure a job to only run when all conditions are met, for instance, in a Pipeline Schedule and on master branch?

I would suggest that we should use `rules` instead of `only` in GitLab pipelines. For example, this should work for running a pipeline on `master/main` when it is scheduled.

```
job:
  script:
    - echo "Hello"
  rules:
    - if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == 'schedule' && $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```